# Image Size Creating Timer Problems

Tags: java, swing, timer, background

The Swing.Timer for my game works depending on the size of the image that I am importing for my background. When I import the image as size 1920 x 1080 the timer is insanely slow and barely updates at all, but it is perfect quality. When the image size is set as 50 x 50 the timer works perfectly but the image itself is incredibly distorted. Is there a way to fix this in java? The code is shown below:

Load Image Class:

```
    public class BufferedImageLoader {
    Image image;
    public Image loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Get Loaded image

```
    public class ImageLoader {
    BufferedImageLoader bif = new BufferedImageLoader();
    public Image spaceship() {
        return bif.loadImage("/objects/spaceship.png");
    }

    public Image background() {
        return bif.loadImage("/objects/spaceBackground.png");
    }
    public Image asteroid1() {
        return bif.loadImage("/objects/v.png");
    }
    public Image background2() {
        return bif.loadImage("/Other/background.png");
    }
}
```

Code where I am having the problem:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(menu)
        ms.render(g2);
    if(game) {
        g2.drawImage(il.background2(), 0, 0, 1000, 750, this);
        g2.drawImage(il.spaceship(), dx, 600, 100, 100, this);
    }
    if(settings)
        ss.render(g2);
    if(credits)
        cs.render(g2);

}
```

il is the ImageLoader Object
I found out when the problem is happening, I just don't really understand why it is happening...

EDIT: For anyone wondering, when I made the background size 1000, 750 (this size that I am drawing it as) the timer is the same as the 1920 x 1080 image, incredibly slow and clunky.

Comment: Loading images is time consuming - you should load them once and pre-cache them - you especially shouldn't try to continually load them in your `paintComponent` method

Comment: Okay, I am going to try and preload the image and then just paint in inside the paintComponent method, will be right back.   EDIT: Wow that fixed everything. I feel so dumb now that I didn't figure out/fix this before. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of software development, where even the brightest are made to feel dumb on regular bases ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading images is time consuming.  You'd be better of pre-loading and caching your images and simply re-using them, for example.

```
public enum BufferedImageLoader {
    INSTANCE;
    private Map<String, BufferedImage> cache = new HashMap<>();
    public Image loadImage(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = cache.get(path);
        if (image == null) {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(path));
                cache.put(path, image);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Then you could just do...

```
public class ImageLoader {
    public Image spaceship() {
        return BufferedImageLoader.INSTANCE.loadImage("/objects/spaceship.png");
    }
```

As a general rule of thumb, don't do anything in your paint methods which might take time to perform, paint should run as fast a possible